# Angular Material => scrolling drop down menu inside a scrolling modal => detached drop-down menu when scrolling outside of drop-down and inside modal

Tags: angular, angular-material

Imagine there is an angular material drop-down inside a modal and both of them have scrolling content. When opening the drop-down and scrolling with the Mouse wheel, if the cursor is on the modal (outside of drop-down) content, the drop-down panel is detached from drop-down.

How is it possible to lock the scroll inside drop down?

I checked 'cdkScrollable' on parent component, because the parent of modal is not 'body' bot it is only work on modal scrolling effect, not drop-down inside a modal.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a long running bug according to [this link](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/11478).